# Jetpack Compose: Dynamically expanding view item size when swipe up/down

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a dynamic screen view for where I have, for example, as in the attachment

- Box 1: LazyColumn
- Box 2: LazyColumn

[image]

For example, as above with **swipe up** Box 2, I want it to **occupy the entire view** of the screen.

Then on **swipe down** Box 2 returns to its **previous size**, let's say half the size of the screen.

My question is how to catch the user's gestures and implement such logic, maybe there is already a ready library or a similar solution?
Any tip will be helpful.